# Website reload after page orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one page responsive website and I don't want it to `reload/refresh` after page orientation. How can I prevent this?

Comment: It won't reload by default, please show your code...

Comment: Prevent what - the page reload? It shouldn't usually reload when you change orientation. On what kind of device, in what kind of browser?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the page to adapt to the new screen width on page orientation changes? (That's not a reload/refresh.) If so, and assuming you're defining media breakpoints in CSS, then then you can include orientation states in the media queries.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your code and/or an live example, it greatly improves your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add this piece of javascript to page:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    switch(window.orientation){
      case -90:
        contentType = "rotated-right";
      break;

      case 90:
        contentType = "rotated-left";
      break;
    }
    $('html').removeClass('rotated-left').removeClass('rotated-right').addClass('rotated-' + orientation)
});
```

And this css:

```
html.rotated-right {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

html.rotated-left {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: I pretty much want it to function as yahoo.com functions during page orientation. As you can see their page does not reload/refresh during landscape/portrait mode. I am testing my site on an ipad in Safari. url: http://mktminc.com/ecraftinc/

Comment: Yahoo site works exactly the same as yours for me. What do you mean by "reload/refresh"?

Comment: methyl: When I say refresh/reload I mean when you click the refresh arrow in the address bar.

Comment: So, it doesn't reload for me.